# DataTrigger not working in WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following WPF ListView where I change the template depending on the property **ChangeView** in my class **MyItemsClass**.

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type myClass:MyItemsClass}}, Path=ChangeView}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource largeTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type myClass:MyItemsClass}}, Path=ChangeView}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource smallTemplate }" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </ListView.Style>
```

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="largeTemplate">
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True">
        <WrapPanel.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyData}">
                <Button Command="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
                        <Image Height="100" Width="100"  Source="{Binding Path=MyImage}"/>
                </Button>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </WrapPanel.Resources>
    </WrapPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

smallTemplate is the same as largeTemplate XAML only with different sizes of iamge.

Now I want to 'skin' my ListView with an existing style of ListView so if I do the following it works

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyStyle}">

</ListView>

<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter> 
</Style>
```

So now I am attempting to add in the original triggers like so:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyStyle}">

</ListView>

<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter> 

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type myClass:MyItemsClass}}, Path=ChangeView}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource largeTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type myClass:MyItemsClass}}, Path=ChangeView}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource smallTemplate }" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But now my DataTriggers do not work - the ListView.ItemsPanel does not change when my class variable is changed.  How canI get this to work?

Comment: These should not be combined into one style.  The triggers are part of the style for the ListBox itself, while the rest of the style is for the individual items.

Comment: ok, how do I add two styles to a ListView then??

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{DynamicResource MyStyle}">

</ListView>

<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}">
   <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter> 

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type myClass:MyItemsClass}}, Path=ChangeView}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource largeTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type myClass:MyItemsClass}}, Path=ChangeView}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource smallTemplate }" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I changed your style to target the Style of the ListView itself, rather than its ItemContainerStyle property, and then I changed `<Setter Property="Template">` to `<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">` so that it will only override the template for your items, rather then overriding the template for the whole `ListView`.

Comment: Still the same I'm afraid - changing 'ChangeView' does not trigger the ListView.ItemsPanel to change.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a working `ListView` style? Why don't you simply set the `ItemContainerStyle` property of it to your "MyStyle"?:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyStyle}">
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type myClass:MyItemsClass}}, Path=ChangeView}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource largeTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type myClass:MyItemsClass}}, Path=ChangeView}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource smallTemplate }" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
</ListView>
```

MyStyle applies to a `ListViewItem` and not to a `ListView` so this should work.

Or what is the "skin" that you are trying to apply?